# Python Pandas MA for irregular dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to calculate a rolling moving average for a data set that is time stamped in ms, but is irregular. For a 2 day dataframe, the irregular data set has ~36K records. If I resample into ms bars, I melt the computer and there become 32M bars.

To be clear, consider the following data set taken from the Pandas [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html):
(I've changed the NaN to 0)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 1, 2, np.nan, 4]},index = 
     [pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:00'),
                        pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:02'),
                        pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:03'),
                        pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:05'),
                        pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:06')])

df.rolling('2s').mean()
                       B
2013-01-01 09:00:00  0.0
2013-01-01 09:00:02  1.0
2013-01-01 09:00:03  1.5
2013-01-01 09:00:05  0.0
2013-01-01 09:00:06  2.0
```

But the answer I'd like is:

```
df.rolling('2s').mean()
                           B
    2013-01-01 09:00:00  0.0
    2013-01-01 09:00:02  0.5
    2013-01-01 09:00:03  1.5
    2013-01-01 09:00:05  1.0
    2013-01-01 09:00:06  2.0
```

This has the entries rolled forward (ffill style) in order to calc the mean. I'd like to solve this problem without exploding the memory usage and without just going through it sequentially (which I know I can do).

I had thought that something like:

```
df.rolling('2s', freq='1s').mean()
```

would work but it throws off an error expecting 7 rows but having only 5 (ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1,5), indices imply (1,7)).

If I resample into another dataframe using pad and then do a rolling mean, it works:

```
df2 = df.resample('1s').pad()
df2.rolling('2s').mean()
```

Is there a built in for this? Or do I just iterate through?